# Update Statement for Last Card Status

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, dml

I have a card with cardstatus: 1 (open)

I got another card with cardstatus: 2 (closed)

I run a job that makes both of the cards on cardstatus: 3 (Hold)

Now, I want to write an update statement where it would set both of the cards to their previous statuses. I just gave you 1 and 1 cards as examples.

In reality there are 1000s of cards and obviously I don't want to write that many update statements and I don't want to change the current code that much. Currently, the logic in update statement puts all hold cards (cardstatus 3) to active (cardstatus 1).

card table has cardstatus (current status)

cardaudit table has cardstatus (prevous card statuses)

max(cardauditid) in cardaudit table would always be the laststatus --- this is what I want instead of all cards to active status

card and cardaudit tables have cardstatus in common

I am trying to write:

```
update card set cardstatus = (some query to get the previous status)
```

Update!!!

I got the answer.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please see above....I provided sample data.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier with sample data, but still:

```
create table credit (tid int, stat varchar(10))

insert into credit values (1,'hold'),(2,'hold')

create table creditaudit (id int identity, tid int, stat varchar(10))

insert into creditaudit (tid, stat) 
values (1,'open'), (1,'close'), (2,'open'), (1,'active'), (2,'close')

select * from  credit
select * from  creditaudit

;with cte 
as (select tid, stat, row_number() over(partition by tid order by id desc) rn
    from creditaudit)
select * from credit
    join cte on credit.tid = cte.tid
where rn = 1
```